# Is $|Aut(S_4\times \mathbb{Z})| \ge 24$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is $|Aut(S_4 \times \mathbb{Z})| \ge 24$?

I know there is some easy theorem/lemma to apply for this case but I just can't seem to recall what it is. Is there an easy theorem to prove/disprove the above inequality?

Comment: It seemed likely to me that the group you were asking about is the one in the question body, and the parens in the title were mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

You already have $Aut(S_4)\simeq S_4$ because $S_4$ is centerless and every automorphism is inner. So $|Aut(S_4)|=24$.

Now if $G=H\times K$ and $\sigma \in Aut(H)$, then you can define $\sigma'\in Aut(G)$ by $\sigma'(h,k)=(\sigma(h),k)$, so $Aut(H)$ is a subgroup of $Aut(G)$.

Here it means that $S_4$ is a subgroup of $Aut(S_4\times \mathbb{Z})$. In fact since $\mathbb{Z}$ also has automorphisms, you easily see that $S_4\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of order $48$.

Answer (score 0):

For every auotmorphism $\phi$ of $S_4$ there is a corresponding automorphism $(\phi,1)$ of $S_4\times\mathbb{Z}$. And $\mathrm{Aut}(S_4)\simeq S_4$, which has order $24$. So yes, the order is at least 24.